# How to get GitHub commit notifications by email after January

Tags: github

I'm part of several teams that depend heavily on GitHub's convenient "send an email every time anyone pushes commits" service, which is slated to disappear in a few weeks.  I'm aware that it's been deprecated in favor of a more general WebHooks mechanism, but the docs are not very clear on exactly how one would instantiate the general mechanism to get back what the existing one does.

What is the *easiest* way to replicate the functionality that's going away?

Answer (score 10):

Beside the [original post](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/replacing-github-services/#replacing-services-with-webhooks) (Replacing Services with webhooks), you have:

- [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), still in beta, but which should make it possible to accomplishes this ([registration here](https://github.com/features/actions/signup/?account=)).
- [efforts made to look for a webhook-based alternative](https://github.com/BOINC/boinc/issues/2502).
  For instance: [`pyinstaller/pyinstaller` issue 3579](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3579). But there are no clear answer yet.
  Update Feb. 2020: this issue is [now closed](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3579#event-3072145287) (GitHub Actions are very much the standard now)

Comment: Thank you -- GitHub Actions do indeed seem promising.

(I'm still surprised that apparently no one has implemented a turnkey solution already.  Are there really so few people wanting an email per push on a repo that they own or contribute heavily to?  Seems like a very natural mode of use to me, but perhaps I have a deep misunderstanding of the Right Way to get work done with git...)

Comment: Here is confirmation from GitHub that "it should be possible to build an Action that accomplishes this": https://twitter.com/mcolyer/status/1068304552372273153

Comment: It would be great if someone with access to the GitHub Actions beta could try this out. Unfortunately, I have no beta access.

Comment: @CatalinHritcu you can register for their beta here -> https://github.com/features/actions/signup/?account=

Comment: @cecilmerrelakabringrainfire Tried to register for the beta a week back, but so far no answer.

Comment: I've also tried to register, with similar (i.e. no) results so far.

Comment: It seems slightly ridiculous that there apparently isn't currently a straightforward way to retain push notification emails. This seems like a very common use case and I would have expected GitHub to provide some kind of transition path by now, especially as they're going to stop working at the end of January 2019.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, GitHub has now restored the previous functionality and even documented it again: https://help.github.com/articles/about-email-notifications-for-pushes-to-your-repository